# Cannot convert argument from const A to A

Tags: c++, oop

I have a little problem when I try to run the following piece of code. I get the error: "Cannot convert argument from const A to A". Intellisense tells me that A has no suitable copy constructor, however one is defined.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int x, *y;
public: A(int i) { x = i; y = new int[x]; }
        A(A& a) { x = a.x; y = new int[x]; }
        int get_x() const { return x; }
};

int f(A a) { return a.get_x(); }
int main() {
    const A a(5);
    cout << (a.get_x() == f(a));
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: It says that "no *suitable* copy constructor" was found. Yours isn't suitable for copying a `const` object.

Answer (score 2):

Your copy constructor should have the prototype:

```
A(const A & a)
```

Answer (score 0):

While building the temprary for the call

```
int f(A a) { return a.get_x(); }
```

you need to build an `A` out of a `const A`, but the constructor requires an `A &`